# Relationship between categories and products

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have two categories that are link to the table post. Each category contains a list of airport and city name.

**A city can have many airports**, i would like when a user click on the category for ex:[Paris - New york], all the flight(airports) between these two cities have to be display.

For now with what i have done if a user click on [Paris - New york] only all the flight from New york to every direction will be display and i don't want that.

This is how my `CategoriesArrival` and `CategoriesDeparture` look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | name       | city                         |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1  |Kennedy    | New York                     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  2  |La Guardia | New York                     |
--------------------------------------------------
|  3  |Charles de Gaulle| Paris                  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  4  |Orly       | Paris                        |
--------------------------------------------------
|  5  |Cape Town  | Cape Town                    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

<kbd>CategoriesArrival.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;
use FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CategoriesArrival
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="CategoriesArrival", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="name", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\CategoriesArrivalRepository")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CategoriesArrival
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="airport1")
     *
     */
    private $ItemCategories;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=125)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=4, nullable=true)
     */
    private $code;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ItemCategories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }









    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return CategoriesArrival
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return CategoriesArrival
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }



    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return CategoriesArrival
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }



    /**
     * Add ItemCategories
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post $itemCategories
     * @return CategoriesArrival
     */
    public function addItemCategory(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post $itemCategories)
    {
        $this->ItemCategories[] = $itemCategories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ItemCategories
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post $itemCategories
     */
    public function removeItemCategory(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post $itemCategories)
    {
        $this->ItemCategories->removeElement($itemCategories);
    }

    /**
     * Get ItemCategories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getItemCategories()
    {
        return $this->ItemCategories;
    }
}
```

The CategoriesDeparture.php look exatcly like the CategoriesArrival.php

<kbd>Post.php</kbd>

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesDeparture", inversedBy="ItemCategories")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 *
 */
private $airport;



/**
 *
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesArrival", inversedBy="ItemCategories")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 *
 */
private $airport1;
```

<kbd>PostController.php</kbd>

```
public function categoryAction($entity)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->byCategory($entity);
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:category.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
}


public function category1Action($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:CategoriesArrival')->findBy(array('id' => $id));
    return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:category1.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));
}
```

<kbd>category1.twig.html</kbd>

```
   {% for entity in entities %}


        <li>
            <a class="cd-nav-item" href="{{ path('categorieProducts', { 'entity' : entity.id, 'slug':entity.city}) }}">
                <img src="{{  asset('bundles/flyplatform/img/blog1.jpg')}}">
                <h3>{{ entity.city }}</h3>
            </a>
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
```

<kbd>index.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% render (controller('FLYBookingsBundle:Post:category1', { 'id':  2 })) %}
```

<kbd>Routing.yml</kbd>

```
categorieProducts:
     pattern:  /category/{entity}
     defaults: { _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Post:category }
```

<kbd>PostRepository.php</kbd>

```
public function byCategory($entity)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->where('u.airport1 = :airport1')
        ->orderBy('u.id')
        ->setParameter('airport1', $entity);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

ADD:

[image: Model]

Comment: it's a mistake.....I meant Cape Town.

Comment: "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." This question makes clear that naming things is very hard, even without spelling mistakes ;-). You mentioned 'products' in your question, but I can't find in your code. And what is a 'CategoriesArrival'? Fix your naming or show your database model.

Comment: You are only filtering on airport1. In the anchor you would need to pass both depart and arrival city and then filter on both of those.

Comment: @StephanVierkant , I added i picture of the model on top in the question.  @Nerdlyist do you have an example to show how to do it ? Should i call in my  `categoryAction` both table and each entity with his own query builder?

Comment: Why don't you have airport_departure (or 'from') and airport_arrival (or 'to') and point them to the same table (Airport)? I think your model is too complicated. And your 'post' table has a username. If a 'post' is a user, what if the same user has another flight?

Comment: A User can add the route where is going to and the place is leaving from.Each Post is link to a User Id, in the table Post I added a column username because when the Post that the user added is purchased and an email will be sent with the name of the owner of the Post. In the future I should change  CategoriesDeparture to From and CategoriesArrival to To. The CategoriesDeparture and CategoriesArrival are display in a dropdown so the User when is adding a Post he can select the place is leaving from and going To.

Comment: So your list of arrival airports differs from your departure airports?

Comment: The list of Arrival airports and departure are the same.